# Java program to read JSON and create a new Java class

Tags: java, json

I need to write a Java program which will read JSON and create a new Java class. New Java class member details like name, datatype will be configured in the JSON.

For e.g for below JSON : -

```
 {
    "className": "MyPojo",
    "fieldName": "age",
    "dataType": "int"
}
```

Class to be created : -

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private int age;

    public int getAge ()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge (int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is well suited on Freelancer site

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Can you have a look at the following git 
  https://github.com/astav/JsonToJava

Comment: Creating Java class from JSON is very non-trivial task. Creating **instance of a class** from JSON data, on the other hand, is pretty trivial, and there is a bunch of libraries that specialize in just that. You will have to look for them yourself, though - this is the site that deals with specific problems, not writes your code instead of you.

Comment: Thanks for all your valuable inputs.... After investigating more on this i got some useful link which helped me... just sharing so that in future might help other people   : -  https://dzone.com/articles/converting-json-to-pojos-using-java

Answer (score 0):

After investigating more on this i got some useful link which helped me... just sharing so that in future might help other people : - dzone.com/articles/converting-json-to-pojos-using-java